# mod_rewrite path info postfix and per-dir prrefix

Tags: apache-http-server, htaccess, mod-rewrite

There's an issue with .htaccess configuration.

I just need the url **/category** to match the **category.php** script, but when I try to open this url, there's a 404 error instead.

Here's my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^category/ category.php [QSA,L]
```

htaccess log:

```
init rewrite engine with requested uri /category/
[www.test.com/sid#7fc1c2694dd0][rid#7fc1c25f00a0/initial] pass through /category/
[www.test.com/sid#7fc1c2694dd0][rid#7fc1c25e80a0/subreq] [perdir /home/ubuntu/domains/test.com/public_html/] add path info postfix: /home/ubuntu/domains/test.com/public_html/category.php -> /home/ubuntu/domains/test.com/public_html/category.php/
[www.test.com/sid#7fc1c2694dd0][rid#7fc1c25e80a0/subreq] [perdir /home/ubuntu/domains/test.com/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/ubuntu/domains/test.com/public_html/category.php/ -> category.php/
[www.test.com/sid#7fc1c2694dd0][rid#7fc1c25e80a0/subreq] [perdir /home/ubuntu/domains/test.com/public_html/] applying pattern '^category/' to uri 'category.php/'
[www.test.com/sid#7fc1c2694dd0][rid#7fc1c25e80a0/subreq] [perdir /home/ubuntu/domains/test.com/public_html/] pass through /home/ubuntu/domains/test.com/public_html/category.php
```

And the result is 404 error by Apache: Not Found

The requested URL /category/ was not found on this server.

If I open **/category.php** directly, it works.

Here's the vhost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.com
    ServerAlias www.test.com

    ServerRoot /home/ubuntu/domains/test.com
    DocumentRoot public_html
    <Directory "/home/ubuntu/domains">
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    RewriteEngine On
    LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3

    ErrorLog logs/error.log
    CustomLog logs/access.log combined

        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/json
        DeflateCompressionLevel 9
</VirtualHost>
```

Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)

Server built:   Jul 22 2014 14:36:38

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and replaced

```
Options MultiViews
```

with

```
Options  -MultiViews
```

Actually I ended up with

```
Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```

I found that  solution here:

https://velenux.wordpress.com/2012/07/17/apache-mod_rewrite-multiple-add-path-info-postfix/